# Why can't this textarea assume the full height of its parent in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, textarea

Consider the following page, which displays a line of text with a `<textarea>` underneath it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.expand {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p>
    Nice little wall of text.
  </p>
  <div class="expand">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

The intended behavior is to have the textarea occupy the remaining height of the page underneath the line of text. Using flexbox, I can make the `.expand` element occupy the remaining height of the page. However, despite having `height: 100%;` set on the textarea it refuses to occupy the full height of its parent.

Why isn't this working and how can I make the textarea fill its parent?

Comment: I'm a little confused; you want to know why it won't expand to full height *without* `flex-grow: 1` on the parent?

Comment: @TylerH it won't expand _with_ `flex-grow: 1;` set on the parent.

Comment: Ah, it *is* working correctly up until the point you resize it manually, at least in Firefox. IIRC, auto adjustment doesn't happen anymore after you manually resize it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.expand {
  flex: 1;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p>
    Nice little wall of text.
  </p>
  <div class="expand">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.expand {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `.expand` div actually does work as intended. It occupies the remaining height of the parent.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.expand {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p>Nice little wall of text.</p>
  <div class="expand">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the `textarea` is a child of `.expand`, and you've set it to `height: 100%`.

Since percentage heights are normally based on the specified height of the parent, and there is no `height` defined on `.expand`, the `textarea` height computes to `auto` (more complete explanations [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)).

The simplest and most efficient solution is to get rid of the percentage height on the `textarea` and give the parent `display: flex`, which automatically applies `align-items: stretch` to the child.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.expand {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  display: flex;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p>
    Nice little wall of text.
  </p>
  <div class="expand">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TylerH, yes, you're right. The problem doesn't exist in FF / Edge. The second [**link reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276) in my answer covers this in detail. In fact, taking your comment into consideration, this post may even be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
.expand {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

to

```
.expand {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a concept of block width/height as "[definite](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#definite)" or "indefinite"; essentially .

Percentages need to have a definite length to resolve against, and Chrome doesn't consider flex items `definite` in this case, contrary to the current spec.

There are two easy fixes here: either set `flex-basis` to a `<length>` (when it's the only flex item that can grow, it doesn't actually matter what length this is, it just can't be the other values of `none` or `auto`, so `flex-basis: 0` works fine), or give it a definite height (and it similarly doesn't matter, so `height: 0` works fine).

Alternatively, you can make `.expand` itself a flexbox with the `textarea` child expanding to fill the parent as one of the other answers suggests.